# Store the total and have it cumulate on submit

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, local-storage, cumulative-sum

How do you store the total and have it cumulate each time a user hits submit?

For instance, `Cumulative Total = #` would add up the total of column 3 each time a user submits their info.

```
<body ng-app="Test">
  <section style="margin-top:80px">

    <h3>Plastic Calculator Form</h3>

    <div ng-controller="TestController as test" >
      <p>To date, <strong><u># of people who pledged</u></strong> Earthlings have pledged to reduce their single-use plastic waste from <strong><u>{{ test.approve | sumByColumn: 'amount' }}</u></strong> Items per year to <strong><u>{{(test.approve | sumByColumn: 'amount') - (test.approve | sumByColumn4: 'reducedTotal')}}</u></strong>. That's a reduction of <strong><u>{{ test.approve | sumByColumn4: 'reducedTotal' }}</u></strong> per year!  Do your part.  Make a pledge!</p>
      <table class="table">
        <tr>
          <th>Single-Use Plastic Items</th>
          <th>Enter the Number You Use Per Week</th>
          <th>The Number You Use Per Year is:</th>
          <th>How Many Less Can You Use Per Week?</th>
          <th>Your Reduced Usage Per Year Would Be:</th>
        </tr>

        <tr ng-repeat="x in test.approve">
          <td> {{ x.name }} </td>
          <td> <input class="qty form-control" type="number" ng-model="x.number" ng-change="sumByColumn3()" min="0" restrict-to="[0-9]"/> </td>
          <td> {{ x.number*x.amount }} </td>
          <td> <input class="qty form-control" type="number" ng-model="x.reducedAmount" ng-change="sumByColumn2()" min="0" restrict-to="[0-9]"/> </td>
          <td> {{ x.reducedAmount*x.reducedTotal }} </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TOTALS</td>
          <td>{{ test.approve | sumByColumn3: 'number' }}</td>
          <td>{{ test.approve | sumByColumn: 'amount' }}</td>
          <td>{{ test.approve | sumByColumn2: 'reducedAmount' }}</td>
          <td>{{ test.approve | sumByColumn4: 'reducedTotal' }}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2">Total difference = {{(test.approve | sumByColumn: 'amount') - (test.approve | sumByColumn4: 'reducedTotal')}}</td>
          <td colspan="3">
            <strong>Cumulative Total = #</strong>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <form>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="full-name">Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="full-name" placeholder="Enter Full Name">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email-address">Email</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email-address" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-top:25px">Submit</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </section>

</body>
```

**[Link to Pen](https://codepen.io/tampham/pen/RzqLQV)**

I am not really sure if its best to do with `window.localStorage` or `sessionStorage` or perhaps do it with PHP. I'm experimenting with this now.

Your help will be golden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am not really sure if its best to do with window.localStorage or
>   sessionStorage or perhaps do it with PHP. I'm experimenting with this
>   now.

Its simple to figure this out. Here is how:

1.) Have these numbers (summation) somehow got anything to do with your backend data? Do you need some kind of server code or functionalities to do this? if yes: **use php**.

2.) If 1 was false for you, do you want your users to be able to get the numbers or summation back again when they come back again? do you want it to be **persistent**? then use: **localStorage**

3.) If 2 was false, use sessionStorage. it is not persistent and is cleared out as soon as the current session is terminated. ie: user closes the tab or browser.

Now if you need some help with code, then modify your question to include those details or open a new question or simply post a comment on this answer of mine. I would try my best to help you out. Happy Coding!

Comment: Thanks for providing these points, it's very helpful. My goal is to save and display the total after a user submits their data. So when another person visits the form, they will see that the ```Cumulative Total = #``` has grown larger than before. I've tried ```localStorage``` method but it seems to only save it locally, only I could see it, no one else could. So method #1 might be the way to go, I'll see what I can come up with.

Comment: @Tam sure. that sounds good. i would like to suggest that you use both of them for a better user experience. example: save the last total value you got fro your server into localStorage so that even if the user is offline or unable to connect, he/she is still able to see something meaningful from recent past. And again, if you share some code, I might be able to help you with it in a more particular way, especially when it comes to localStorage and saving and interpreting data client-side.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, since this app will be living on a WordPress environment, I've figured it out using a plugin called Running Totals for Gravity Forms to accumulate the totals. Issue resolved.